# how to display the database table list in dropdown using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Please anyone suggest how to display data in dropdown list?
what code will be use in option attribute?**

**My Controller**

```
public function tableReports()
{
    $data['tables']=$this->DbReports->selectTable('snehal_pharma');
    $this->load->view('reports/rpt.php');

}
```

**Model Code**

```
function selectTable($db)
    {
        $query=$this->db->list_tables();
        print_r($query);
        return $query;
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="span12">
                                Table List :
                                <select name="tbl" style="width: 150px;">
                                    <?php foreach($tables->result() as $tbl){ ?>
                                    <option><?php echo $tbl;?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

**Output**

> Array ( [0] => account_groups [1] => account_undergroup [2] => batch_master [3] => batch_packing [4] => batch_stock [5] => company_master [6] => cost_sheet [7] => cost_sheet_details [8] => customer [9] => departments [10] => disp_material [11] => dm_gatepass [12] => equipment_master [13] => es_finance_master [14] => es_ledger [15] => es_voucher [16] => es_voucherentry [17] => exipient [18] => mail_date [19] => pm_issue [20] => purchase [21] => purchase_details [22] => purchase_indent [23] => purchase_items [24] => purchase_master [25] => purchase_order [26] => sales [27] => sales_details [28] => sales_items [29] => sales_master [30] => sop_master [31] => stock_register [32] => stockcategory [33] => stockmaster [34] => supplier_master [35] => supply_order [36] => taxcategories [37] => tbl_state [38] => tbluser [39] => unit_pack [40] => unitsofmeasure [41] => view_salesledger [42] => viewbatchstock [43] => www_users [44] => zformulamaster [45] => zpackmaster )

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo $tbl;?>"><?php echo $tbl;?></option>`

Comment: not working i tried

Comment: what you mean `not working` . is there any error ?

Comment: check my answer mam

Answer (score 2):

You can access your array keys like so:

`foreach ($array as $key => $value)`

First check `var_dump($tables->result())`, How is your value printing. Then change your code to something like below.

```
<?php foreach($tables->result() as $key => $value){ ?>

<option value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $value;?></option>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: atleast you got the idea

Answer (score 0):

use these in foreach loop and optin attribute

```
<?php foreach($tabls as $tbl){ ?>
    <option><?php echo $tbl;?></option>
<?php } ?>
```